# Setting TextView text from another class

Tags: java, android

I want to update a TextView from an Asynch Thread so I tried to do it with a Callback Method. The problem is that the callback is invoked but no text changes within the TextView.

This is the Callback Interface:

```
interface MyCallBack {
    public void UpdateMyText(String mystr);
}
```

This is the Activity (incomplete) code:

```
package it.italprogetti.datalogic;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.*;
import com.datalogic.*;

public class Scan extends AppCompatActivity implements MyCallBack {

    private final String LOGTAG = getClass().getName();
    String mes = "";
    BarcodeManager decoder = null;
    ReadListener listener = null;
    TextView message = null;
    TextView message2 = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);

    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanMessage);
    message2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanMessage2);

    final MyCallBack scan = this;

    Log.i(LOGTAG, "onResume");

    // If the decoder instance is null, create it.
    if (decoder == null) { // Remember an onPause call will set it to null.
        decoder = new BarcodeManager();
    }

    // From here on, we want to be notified with exceptions in case of errors.
    ErrorManager.enableExceptions(true);

    try {

        // Create an anonymous class.
        listener = new ReadListener() {

            // Implement the callback method.
            @Override
            public void onRead(DecodeResult decodeResult) {
                // Change the displayed text to the current received result.
                new RetrieveFeedTask(scan).execute(decodeResult);
            }

        };

        // Remember to add it, as a listener.
        decoder.addReadListener(listener);

    } catch (DecodeException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error while trying to bind a listener to BarcodeManager", e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "onPause");
    // If we have an instance of BarcodeManager.
    if (decoder != null) {
        try {
            // Unregister our listener from it and free resources.
            decoder.removeReadListener(listener);

            // Let the garbage collector take care of our reference.
            decoder = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error while trying to remove a listener from BarcodeManager", e);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void UpdateMyText(String mystr) {
    Log.i("CALLBACK", "CALLBACK INVOKED!" + mystr);
    message2.setText(mystr);
    ViewGroup vg = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    vg.invalidate();
}
```

And this is the Asynch Task class:

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<DecodeResult, String, String> {

    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.9.200.23/automazione";
    private static final String user = "root";
    private static final String pass = "root";
    private Exception exception;


    MyCallBack mCallBack = null;

    public RetrieveFeedTask(MyCallBack callback) {
        Log.i("CREATO ASYNCH", "ASYNCH");
        this.mCallBack = callback;
    }


    protected String doInBackground(DecodeResult... codes) {

        try {


            String codice = codes[0].getText();
            codice = codice.substring(0, 8);
            Log.i("SCAN", "SCANNED" + codice);
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            String result = "Database connection success\n";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            Log.i("SCAN", "select * from utenti where code='" + codice + "'");
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from utenti where code='" + codice + "'");

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Log.i("OPERATOR IDENTIFIED", rs.getString(4));
                this.mCallBack.UpdateMyText("OPERATOR IDENTIFIED " + rs.getString(2));

            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        // TODO: check this.exception
        // TODO: do something with the feed
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone explain me what happens, please?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes I was getting an error trying to update the UI from anpther thread. I solved using the  onProgressUpdate() method from the AsynchTask class  (as Marcos suggested me).

Comment: Next time add the Exception Stacktrace at the Question body so we can answer faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is suposed to break with Exception cause you are touching your Views from a Thread that not created it. The solution on AsyncTasks is using the publishProgress from inside doInBackground and handle in the overrided onProgressUpdated to call the callback since this piece of code will be on the original Thread, such:

```
public SomeTask extends AsyncTask<DecodeResult, String, String> {
    private Container container;
    public someTask(Container container){
        this.container = container; 
    }
    public void doInBackground(String ... args) { 
        while (rs.next()) {
            Log.i("OPERATOR IDENTIFIED", rs.getString(4));
            publishProgress("OPERATOR IDENTIFIED " + rs.getString(2));
        }
    }
    void onProgressUpdate(String step){
         this.mCallBack.updateMyText(step);
    }
}
```

If you app is not crashing so you need to make sure that the Task was started from the Listener you created. Debug it to see.

Obs: Please use Java naming conventions with methods starting with low case letters.

Comment: Hi Marcos, thank you for the answer, I didn't really understand the AsynchTask class before. Now it works.